# Problem installing from Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS 32bit cd

Tags: 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Older laptop currently running xp, only 128mb ram too. Is 128 just too small? But, 20+ gigs free hard drive and it's been defragmented. When I try to install Ubuntu from a CD I get the screen that says ubuntu and has the four red dots and then eventually goes blank and I just hear hard drive noises. Stays this way indefinitely (shut it off after half a day). Burned another cd, at slow writing speed too, and dl is from Ubuntu and get same result. Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

128 is way too small. See: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop#System_Requirements
you need a minimum of 384 Mb and that's scraping the bottom of the barrel in performance.

It could be a hardware incompatibility or memory exhaustion that is keeping your install from working. Try http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/index.html